# DS-5 development board support

Tags: arm, ds-5

I am trying to develop an application with HiKey 96 Board. ARM DS-5 claims to support any board with an ARM based SoC. Does it support the HiKey board? In general, how do I find if ARM DS-5 supports a board?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DS-5 needs some glue logic to support any development board.

DS-5 ships with this glue logic for the boards listed in [supported devices](https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/ds-5-development-studio/resources/supported-devices). In other words, DS-5 should work out-of-box with these boards.

If the board is not listed, then check if DS-5 supports the processor in the board. Processors supported are listed [here](https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/ds-5-development-studio/resources/supported-processor-cores). If DS-5 supports the processor inside a board, then DS-5 can be made to work with that board, provided glue logic can be created.

As of now, DS-5 does not have built-in support for HiKey board. However, DS-5 supports  Cortex-A53, the processor in the HiKey board.